# Compress .ipa monotuch

Tags: xamarin.ios, compression, jpeg, ipa

Starting from the assumption that I have deleted all unnecessary files, i have my app that contains a folder with jpg images (1024*700 resolution minimum permitted) where the size is 400 MB. When generate my ipa size is 120 MB. I have tried to convert those images in PNG and next generate ipa but size is more than 120 MB (140 MB), but quality it's a bit worse.

Which best practices recommended to reduce the size of the application?

P.s. Those files are showed as gallery.

Comment: why you put all these images local? can't it be load from web ?

Comment: Compressing 400MB of jpeg images into 120MB is actually an impressive feat... if that's still too much you need to put your images elsewhere (loaded dynamically from some web site for instance).

Comment: My application should work offline...I also thought to pack them with a zip and load them in the IPA and then subsequently decompressing when app it's open, but in this case the resource would be completely charged and would not be compressed as the jpeg by growing exponentially the weight of my app.

Comment: What's the problem? There are apps on the store that are >500MB...? If you're app's purpose is to show certain images, I think it's all fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On tool we used in our game, Draw a Stickman: EPIC, is [smusher](https://github.com/grosser/smusher).

To install (you have to have ruby or XCode command line tools):

`sudo gem install smusher`

It might print some errors installing that you can ignore.

To use it:

```
smusher mypng.png
smusher myjpg.jpg
```

The tool will send the picture off to yahoo's web service `smush.it`, and in a non-lossy way compress the image.

Generally you can save maybe 20% file size with no loss in quality.

There are definitely other techniques we used like using indexed PNGs, but you are already using JPGs, which are smaller.

Comment: with this practice i have reduced size from 5% to 10% of total. It's a  good start. Some tricks also for pdf files?

Comment: Never had to deal with that, you might try what they mention here: http://support.soe.ucsc.edu/web/adobe